# Active choice reactive parameter from single json file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-groovy

I am having a json file as

```
  { "data": [{"location" : "EU",
              "env": ["DEV", "PRD", "UAT"]},
             {"location" : "US",
              "env": ["DEV", "PRD", "UAT", "DR", "VD"]}
]}
```

I am trying below groovy script to have Active choice reactive parameter

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
List Locations = []
def file_data = new File('<above json file path>').text
def jsonParser = new JsonSlurperClassic()
def data = jsonParser().parseText(file_data)
for (details in data.data){
  Locations.add(details.location)
}
return Locations
```

I am getting Locations correctly as Parameters, however, I want to ***use the same file again and try to return environments based on Location using the Active Choice Reactive parameter.***
I tried multiple options but did not get any luck. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by my own:

I used the Active Choice Reactive Parameter with the following groovy script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

def file_data = new File('<above json file path>').text
def jsonParser = new JsonSlurperClassic()
def data = jsonParser().parseText(file_data)
for (details in data.data){
  if (Locations == details.location){
         return details.env
}
}
```

I used reference Parameter as Locations from the Active Choice parameter.